# Can TypeScript module reference chain be ignored?

Tags: typescript

Some TypeScript type definitions have dependencies on other type definitions but with low importance. For example, jsdom.d.ts have node.d.ts and jquery.d.ts dependency only for five lines:

```
import EventEmitter = NodeJS.EventEmitter;
export interface VirtualConsole extends EventEmitter {
  sendTo(console: Console): VirtualConsole;
}

export function jQueryify(window: Window, jqueryUrl: string, callback: (window: Window, jquery: JQuery) => any): void;
```

I don't want to include the whole large node.js and jquery type definition just because of these lines. Is there any way to ignore them **without modifying jsdom.d.ts file and without a dummy definition file**?

Comment: does your typescript code compile?

Comment: Why is this a problem for you? The type definition files do not affect the output at all and the time difference to include or not include them is negligable.

Comment: `TS6053 File not found` error occurs if I do not include those definition files. This is a problem because some definitions files have complex definition reference chain (e.g. atom.d.ts for GitHub Atom). And, hmm, I just don't want them even if reference chain is not complex. :/

Comment: Maybe with [`--skipLibCheck`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8735) (TS 2.0) but I'm unsure.

Comment: The `--skipLibCheck` suppresses `TS2304 Cannot find name JQuery` but it still gives TS6053. It seems I should file a new issue.